# SwiftUI not all strings are localized

Tags: ios, swiftui

SwiftUI didn't translate the string in variable.

I have added:

```
"Name" = "姓名";
```

if I wrote:

```
Text("Name")
```

works good. I can see the label with `姓名`.

If I define a variable like:

```
@State var title = "Name"
Text(title)
```

Then the localization doesn't work. Still in Chinese. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly indicate that your `title` variable is a `LocalizedStringKey`, not a `String`.

```
@State var title: LocalizedStringKey = "Name"
```